# How can a user with 1 rep earn the Citizen Patrol badge?

Tags: support, flags, flag-badges

I've just came across a new SO user ([*user13450655*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13450655/)), who had only 1 reputation (at the time of writing the post), but already earned the [<kbd>Citizen Patrol</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge.

The strange in that is [<kbd>Citizen Patrol</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) is awarded when the user flags a post, but the [<kbd>Flag posts</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) privilege requires 15 rep.

Also, that user has no reputation changes yet, which would have allowed them to flag a post.

So, my question is, how could they flag a post without the privilege or earn the badge without flagging a post?

Here's the screenshot of the user's profile:
[image: Screenshot of user profile]

Comment: Completely unrelated: Does it take some kind of special discipline to never click the green bubble?

Comment: @Scratte Yes, it's quite hard sometimes, and I've already clicked on it accidentally. :D I don't know why do I do that, but it has became a habit...

Comment: I would so love to have your account details, just to click the button every single day... Several times a day perhaps... :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The user flagged [their own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554535/integration-convergence-and-divergence) to recommend that it be closed.

From the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61554535/timeline), I can see that this flag was raised *after* your initial vote to close, but *before* the other two votes to close were cast.

I have no idea why the user raised a "recommend closure" flag on their own post. Apparently, they thought it needed details or clarity.

And I'm not entirely sure how they managed to do that, as I see no indication that they ever had 15 reputation.

Comment: As of now (if I'm right) every type of flag require only 15 rep [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). And if they flagged their own post, then (I think) they were allowed to do so without rep limit, like how you (maybe better to say *I*, as *you* can do anything with any post due to your ️) can delete or edit your own posts regardless of reputation.

Comment: Good point about *all* flags requiring only 15 reputation. I hadn't paid attention that that had been changed. (I personally think flagging should be available even for anonymous users.) But I'm not sure why you accepted the answer.... It basically just says, "Here's what happened, but I have no idea why." I figured you wanted to know why. :-)

Comment: In my previous comment, I've explained that I (think I) realized , **based on what happened** (that I couldn't figure out by myself): (If I'm right) one can flag *their own posts* similarly why one can edit / delete them, without reputation or additional review... I could've written an answer by myself, but I didn't want to. That's why I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 11):

While Cody has answered what seems to have happened in this particular case another way a < 15 rep user could end up with the citizen patrol badge is flagging a comment on their own question or an answer to it. From [allow new users to flag comments on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311459/allow-new-users-to-flag-comments-on-their-own-posts/313203#313203) the following change was made on August 10th, 2018:

> If you can post a comment on a given post, you can also flag comments on that post (new behavior)
>
> You can flag comments on answers to your own questions as well as those on the questions themselves